# I've installed the Admob plugin into my Phonegap project... now what?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Following the [installation instructions on the Admob Phonegap plugin page on GitHub](https://github.com/sainttex/PhoneGap-Android-Native-AdMob), it seems like it's all gone well without errors.

However, even though the functionality is theoretically available, I don't see how to implement it. Where in my Javascript or HTML files do I place code to actually display an Admob ad?

Where do I get that code for the Admob ad?

Just so it's clear, I have added the relevant Java `.JAR` files to my project, I've edited the `.XML` files, so the plugin is enabled. But there is an extra step, which is to actually place an ad somewhere in my web pages. With a Google Adsense ad, I take a snippet of Javascript and place it in my HTML layout. I am trying to figure out how to connect my HTML/Javascript interface to the Admob plugin that I have (successfully) installed in my project.

An answer would ideally say what is the code to put into my HTML/Javascript, and where to put it. Previously I had Google Adsense code, which is not allowed on mobile apps, so I'm trying to figure out what to replace it with. I have a `<DIV>` that previously contained the Google Adsense, so what do I put in it?

Comment: The plugin you linked to is using Android Java code to add the Android Admob SDK. There is even a sample to look at in the link you provided.

Comment: @MorrisonChang: I'm not sure you understand the question. Phonegap uses Javascript and HTML for designing the interface, and I see no Javascript or HTML code on that page. Where exactly is this sample you are referring to?

Comment: Based on Step 4 and this sample: https://github.com/sainttex/PhoneGap-Android-Native-AdMob/blob/master/src/com/phonegap/admob/MainActivity.java it looks like the AdMob Adview will be setup adjacent to your webview which will hold your HTML/Javascript

Comment: @MorrisonChang, thanks for responding, but I don't know what you mean when you say "the AdMob Adview will be setup adjacent to your webview". That doesn't tell me what to put in my Javascript/HTML, or where to put it. I'll edit my question to be yet more clear.

Comment: You don't put anything in your Javascript/HTML. The AdMob AdView doesn't exist inside your webview, its next to it (either on top or bottom) because of the extra native Android code in Step 4. Have you at least run the example with your AdMob credentials?

Comment: @MorrisonChang: Thanks for responding. So you're saying that I don't actually put *anything* in my HTML Javascript? It just automatically appends to the top or bottom? I hadn't tested it yet because I didn't think there was anything to test, because I thought I hadn't completed building it yet. But if you're saying it's going to put it in without me having to create a space for it... I will try later today when I am at my work computer.

Comment: @MorrisonChang: As you described, the Admob ad displays in my app without me having to create a space for it in my HTML/Javascript code.
If you put your explanation into an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin project you linked to is using the Android AdMob SDK which is a Android native component and doesn't require you to add anything to your Phonegap/Cordova HTML/Javascript code in any way. What is happening is that you are modifying your DroidGap Activity and adding a AdMob AdView component along side the WebView which contains your HTML/Javascript.

The code gets the linear layout which your WebView is held and adds in the AdView.

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AdMob_Ad_Unit); 
LinearLayout layout = super.root;
layout.addView(adView);
```

After that it is just initializing the Ad.